Why is Prophet faster than dynamic harmonic regression?
Section 12.2 of Forecasting: Principles and Practice (3rd edition) discusses Facebook's Prophet model. The authors write:

Prophet has the advantage of being much faster to estimate than the [dynamic harmonic regression] models we have considered previously

Dynamic harmonic regression: the regressors are Fourier terms $s(t)$ and the error term is ARMA:
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= s(t) + \eta_t, \\
\eta_t &\sim \text{ARMA}(p,q).
\end{aligned}
In R, the model is estimated by maximum likelihood via state space representation (I think). We can assume auto.arima is used for selecting the lag orders of the error term.
Prophet: the regressors are a piecewise linear trend $g(t)$ and Fourier terms $s(t)$. (There could be holiday dummies $h_t$, too.) The error term is i.i.d. Normal.
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= g(t) + s(t) + \varepsilon_t, \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.d. N(0, \sigma^2).
\end{aligned}
Questions:

Why is Prophet faster to estimate than dynamic harmonic regression?
How general is this finding (short vs. long time series, low vs. high number of Fourier terms, other nuance)?

My initial thoughts (this is not much...):

Bayesian estimation is generally not regarded to be fast.
The selection of lag order via auto.arima can increase the estimation time some 10x (roughly) relative to the situation when the lag order is given.


My money is on 2. The greedy search to re-estimate ARMA (no I?) models on residuals until we have a model that minimizes AICc compared to all neighbor models likely dwarfs the initial regression on Fourier terms in terms of runtime.
